# Unsuccessful boot with Ubuntu 22.04 w/ HP Envy x360

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.04

With Ubuntu 22.04 the boot hangs showing 3 error messages:

1. (1 of 3) A start job is running for Userspace Out-of-memory (OOM) Killer
2. (2 of 3) A start job is running for Network Name Resolution
3. (3 of 3) A start job is running for Userspace Out-of-memory (OOM) Killer

These errors appear when booting with kernel 5.15.0-25-generic. Very occasionally the PC boots correctly with the 5.15 kernel.

If I boot with kernel 5.13.0-39-generic the laptop boots successfully (albeit with suspend not working, brightness keys not working, etc.). I had hoped that kernel 5.15 would perhaps solve the suspend issue, but need to solve the boot issue first.

The laptop is a HP Envy x360 with Ryzen 3300u with radeon vega mobile gfx × 4.

Any ideas?

Comment: Update UEFI before anything else.

Comment: Hi, EUFI BIOS is latest version according to the HP System Update Tool in Windows.

Comment: I have the same issue with HP Envy x360 15 2021. However, Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.10 are booting correctly, everything works. It looks like the issue is related only to 22.04.

Comment: Same with me, HP Envy x360 with AMD Ryzen 5.
Installed Ubuntu yesterday alongside Win10, everything worked fine. But when I turned it on this morning I got same error like you

Comment: I have this exact same issue on an HP Envy (i7 model: 13-ah0560nd). I recently tried upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04 and was confronted this boot issue. Re-installing 20.04 resolved it. However, I just had some updates (still on 20.04), among which a kernel update to 5.15.0.41, which results in the same boot problem again. Booting with kernel 5.13.0.52 works fine.

Comment: 5.15.0-41 not working for HP Aero 13.3 Ryzen 7 16gig ram,1T SSD.  Starts boot but immediately I see listed errors, sometimes it boots to the password screen and then locks up, other time I get past the pwd screen but terminal or some other app locks up, alt+prt sc+REISUB is my only way out besides hard reboot.  For now using change to grub Default="Advanced Ubuntu Options>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-xx-generic" with x equal to the actual number, then sudo update-grub: reboot  Hoping I'll see an answer here to give me a clue.

Comment: I got a boot loop with quiet mode off (deleted) from grub so I could see it, from bluetooth to start job . my issue then was fstab settings were wrong. might be worth checking them, blkid to see the UUIDs then /etc/fstab to check they are correct. I have also been stuck that way when the fstab was fine.

Comment: I updated to kernel 5.18.19-051819-generic, disabled Secure Boot from BIOS and it works fine: networking, suspend, brightness.  `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh/master/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh;  ./ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh  -i v5.18.19`
Another issue I had was that ubuntu live usb did not boot correctly, even Ubuntu 20. So I had to use Arch Linux Live Usb.

Answer (score 0):

I used Ubuntu release of august 22, disabled in windows 11 hibernate mode totally. Then it works on my HP Envy 360 with RYZEN 7 5000 series.
With UEFI update in september 22, all function keys and sleep mode working fine, now.