# Can't access to install ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: boot, kernel, hp, usb-installation

I want to install 22.04 ubuntu LTS version on my hp envy x360 with AMD ryzen 5.
I have similar issue from here:
[Unsuccessful boot with Ubuntu 22.04 w/ HP Envy x360](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403723/unsuccessful-boot-with-ubuntu-22-04-w-hp-envy-x360)

How to solve these issues?
Do you recommend other latest Linux version (maybe different than Ubuntu) I'm trying to install it and configure for third time.. :)

How can I upgrade my bios from GRUB or root boot console?
How can I upgrade my kernel version from GRUB or root boot console?

How to solve these issue to just be happy user of latest ubuntu LTS version.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT
I can run previous linux also 22.04 LTS but without some features on older kernel. but still i need reinstall it

Solution:
On previous linux installed 22.04 I updated kernel and deleted v11 and v15 now I have v19 using:
**Practical Way = Install Ubuntu 22.10**
**Ubuntu 22.10 using KERNEL = 5.19**
https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/pending/

or

**INSTALL Linux Kernel 5.19 to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**
***Kernel 5.19 more better and faster than Kernel 5.15***
Download Kernel 5.19 =

```
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-headers-5.19.0-051900_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_all.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-headers-5.19.0-051900-generic_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.19.0-051900-generic_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-modules-5.19.0-051900-generic_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_amd64.deb
```

Source = [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/)

Now, Install All =

```
sudo apt install ./linux-headers-5.19.0*.deb ./linux-image-unsigned-5.19.0*.deb ./linux-modules-5.19.0*.deb
```

Check Kernel Version =

```
uname -r
```

Output New Kernel 5.19 =

**5.19.0-051900-generic**

Now, Restart your Computer

REMOVE Kernel 5.15 from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS =

```
sudo apt purge linux-headers-5.15.0* linux-modules-5.15.0* linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0*

sudo apt autoremove
```

[How Do I update my kernel to the latest one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388115/how-do-i-update-my-kernel-to-the-latest-one)

Solved

Comment: I solved it -> kernel. problem = can't access to ubuntu 22.04 from boot

Comment: Please write an answer to help future users.

Comment: I wrote. Why you don't read post and gave me -1? :C weird. I linked solution from link I used. P

Comment: Tempted to -1 ...but won't... for arguing with the folks you asked for help. "I linked to a solution" is not how AskUbuntu works. Answers are separate from questions, and are voted upon separately. If you won't write an answer, consider deleting your question.

Comment: ok It is done :)